# I2P HTTP/HTTPS proxies doesn't work

Tags: linux, proxy, i2p

I'm totally new to I2P and trying to configure it so that I could browse ordinary web-pages (eg Linkedin which is blocked in our country right now). At the time of writing the only thing worked properly are .i2p sites like DifTracker:

[image]

I use Arch Linux x64 (4.13.9-1-ARCH) with Firefox. Let me list the steps I did:

**1. Set port forwarding on my router:**

[image]
The port number I took from *Network configuration -> UDP port*. The second line is the same just for Windows.

**2. Set the following proxy settings in Firefox's preferences:**

[image]

**3. Check if I2P tunnels ("outproxies"?) work**. As you can see the network status is OK at the sidebar:

[image]
[image]

**Finally**, I tried to go to reddit but Firefox says proxy server refuses connections:

[image]

**Any ideas?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about I2P, not Tor.

Comment: @canonizingironize sadly, I2P.SE site was closed, so it's the closest StackExchange place where he can ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a checklist to verify:

- First, you need to check allowed clients list.
- Second - IP binding in the proxy service, it should be explicitly `127.0.0.1`, it can be `0.0.0.0` - and in I2P it used to cause some glitches.
- Third - check the logs, a `false.i2p` can be not working, there're other proxies in I2P, try them too. If it is a remote problem - it will tell you in the debug logs

Also a sidenote: if you have not fully bootstrapped your node - it can be just a bootstrap problem, you will have to wait for known nodes like some thousands **and** disappearing of the writing "rejecting tunnels: starting up" - with ports forwarded it takes about 30-40 minutes to get the network-integrated status.

Feel free to ask further questions if you have ones!

Comment: Thank you a lot! At least for the adequate answer instead just voting for close. Unfortunately, I were far away from being questioning you further. So the first one I didn't get is what do you mean by "check allowed clients list"? Wasn't that screen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUCEv.png) what you suggest for?